# Defining DataGrid Templatecolumns at runtime in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

Using the method described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/04/14/defining-silverlight-datagrid-columns-at-runtime.aspx) I'm trying to dynamically build columns DataTemplate.
I've got a problem with defining my own converter. **First** problem is defining my own program name space because I'm getting this error:

*The type 'RowIndexConverter' was not found because 'clr-namespace:LANOS.Models; assembly=LANOS' was not found.*

According to the solution I've based my application on, any user defined name space also requires assembly name. `RowIndexConverter` belongs `LANOS.Models` for sure, there is no typo. Class belongs to main assembly of application (in the other words its not external). So why is there a problem then?

**Second** problem is that I'm not sure if my definition of converter is proper using this technique.
I want to get equivalent of this `UserControl.Resources`:

```
<navigation:Page xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"  x:Class="LANOS.Views.SRFEditor" 
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
           xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
           xmlns:model="clr-namespace:LANOS.Models"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
           Title="SRFEditotr Page">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <model:RowIndexConverter x:Key="rowIndexConverter"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="myCellTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource rowIndexConverter}}' />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Function code.**

```
    private string GenerateTextColumnXAML(string sortMemberKey)
    {
        StringBuilder CellTemp = new StringBuilder();
        CellTemp.Append("<DataTemplate ");
        CellTemp.Append("xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/");
        CellTemp.Append("2006/xaml/presentation' ");
        CellTemp.Append("xmlns:model='clr-namespace:LANOS.Models; assembly=LANOS' ");
        CellTemp.Append("xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' ");
        CellTemp.Append("xmlns:basics='clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;");
        CellTemp.Append("assembly=System.Windows.Controls' >");

        CellTemp.Append("<Grid>");
        CellTemp.Append("<Grid.Resources>");
        CellTemp.Append("<model:RowIndexConverter x:Key='rowIndexConverter' />");
        CellTemp.Append("</Grid.Resources>");

        CellTemp.Append("<TextBlock Text='{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource rowIndexConverter}, ConverterParameter=" + sortMemberKey + "}' />");
        CellTemp.Append("</Grid>");
        CellTemp.Append("</DataTemplate>");
        return CellTemp.ToString();
    }
```

**Result of function:**

```
<DataTemplate
xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' 
xmlns:model='clr-namespace:LANOS.Models; assembly=LANOS' 
xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' 
xmlns:basics='clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls' >
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources><model:RowIndexConverter x:Key='rowIndexConverter' />
</Grid.Resources><TextBlock Text='{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource rowIndexConverter}, ConverterParameter=GRID_ROW_ID}' />
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in this line

```
    CellTemp.Append("xmlns:model='clr-namespace:LANOS.Models; assembly=LANOS' ");
```

Try removing the space before `assembly`, i.e.:

```
    CellTemp.Append("xmlns:model='clr-namespace:LANOS.Models;assembly=LANOS' ");
```

(Yes, I really am asking you to do something as trivial as removing a single space!  I'm surprised that this makes a difference.  I was able to reproduce the error with the space, yet it worked without.)

As for your second question, I don't see a problem with using a converter as you are.  I've done much the same before.

Comment: Oh, I feel a bit silly right now although problem is fixed, thanks for your help :)